# Jest causing "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'isCE')" when upgrading from vue 3.2.37 to 3.2.39

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs

When i upgrade my Vue on my project from `3.2.37` to `3.2.39` I get the following error when running Jest..

```
[UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with the reason "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'isCE')".] {
  code: 'ERR_UNHANDLED_REJECTION'
}
```

If I revert the Vue version the tests run fine. What might be causing the isCE error? Is it some breaking change?

Answer (score 0):

This might be because you may have not mocked a promise in your vue test.

Please read more about this here.

https://v1.test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/testing-async-components.html